# WordPress site suspected of being compromised

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings, fatal-error, require-once

I received a message that a site using WP may have been accessed and compromised.

It's unclear if there is a back up of the site's home directory, still looking into that.

Here's what appears at the site URL `startelecom.ca`

> Warning: require_once(/home/startele/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-menu.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/startele/public_html/wp-content/themes/StarTelecom2/header.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/startele/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-menu.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/startele/public_html/wp-content/themes/StarTelecom2/header.php on line 24

Is there something in the code I can fix?

Thank you for your considerations.

Best regards,
Marc

Comment: so less details and expecting solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Use FTP

Try the following option in priority basis.

1.Delete recently installed plugins. (check the site if it loads)
2.If option 1 doesn't work, Try to upload new wordpress directories and files and over write the older once(try to upload the same version of wordpress you are using currently) and see if the site loads.

And let me know any one of the above options work, If not let us know what are your last actions done one the backend.

Regards,
Raj.

Answer (score -1):

Files were deleted from your theme folder.

Comment: Tom, you were right. Simply overwrote the theme files. All is good.